# Confused on Miller-Rabin

Tags: algorithm, primes, sicp, prime-factoring, primality-test

As an exercise for myself, I'm implementing the Miller-Rabin test. (Working through SICP). I understand Fermat's little theorem and was able to successfully implement that. The part that I'm getting tripped up on in the Miller-Rabin test is this "1 mod n" business. Isn't 1 mod n (n being some random integer) always 1? So I'm confused at what a "nontrivial square root of 1 modulo n" could be since in my mind "1 mod n" is always 1 when dealing with integer values. What am I missing?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not a programming question

Answer (score 28, accepted):

1 is congruent to 9 mod 8 so 3 is a non trivial square root of 1 mod 8.

what you are working with is not individual numbers, but equivalence sets. `[m]n` is the **set** of all numbers `x` such that `x` is congruent to `m` mod `n`.  Any thing that sqaures to any element of this set is a square root of `m` modulo `n`.

given any `n`, we have the set of integers modulo n which we can write as `Zn`. this is the set (of sets) `[1]n`, `[2]n`, ... ,`[n]n`. Every integer lies in one and only one of those sets.  we can define addition and multiplication on this set by `[a]n + [b]n = [a + b]n` and likewise for multiplication. So a square root of `[1]n` is a(n element of) `[b]n` such that `[b*b]n = [1]n`.

In practice though, we can conflate `m` with `[m]n` and normally choose the unique element, `m'` of `[m]n` such that `0 <= m' < n` as our 'representative' element: this is what we usually think of as the `m mod n`. but it's important to keep in mind that we are 'abusing notation' as the mathematicians say.

here's some (non-idiomatic) python code as I don't have a scheme interpreter ATM:

```
>>> def roots_of_unity(n):
...      roots = []
...      for i in range(n):
...          if i**2 % n == 1:
...               roots.append(i)
...      return roots
... 
>>> roots_of_unity(4)
[1, 3]
>>> roots_of_unity(8)
[1, 3, 5, 7]
>>> roots_of_unity(9)
[1, 8]
```

So, in particular (looking at the last example), 17 is a root of unity modulo 9. indeed, 17^2 = 289 and 289 % 9 = 1. returning to our previous notation `[8]9 = [17]9` and `([17]9)^2 = [1]9`

Answer (score 14):

I believe that the misunderstanding comes from the definition the book gives about the nontrivial root:

> a “nontrivial square root of 1 modulo n” , that is, a number not equal to 1 or n - 1 **whose square is equal to 1 modulo n**

Where I believe it should say:

> whose square is **congruent** to 1 modulo n

Comment: I shared the same confusion as the OP, and this clarification made all the difference. The accepted answer is great, but _this_ answer addresses the source of the confusion.

Comment: Here it is September 2020, and I too was just confused by the wording. For someone like me who doesn't have a lot of math, could it also be worded "whose square, modulo n, is equal to 1"?

Answer (score 10):

That is why the wording was for a NONTRIVIAL square root of 1. 1 is a trivial square root of 1, for any modulus n.

17 is a non-trivial square root of 1, mod 144. Thus 17^2 = 289, which is congruent to 1 mod 144. If n is prime, then 1 and n-1 are the two square roots of 1, and they are the only two such roots. However, for composite n there are generally multiple square roots. With n = 144, the square roots are {1,17,55,71,73,89,127,143}.